# How to return a geohash of a geo_point in an Elasticsearch result?

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I return a geohash of a geo_point in an Elasticsearch result?

For example, the location field is a lat/lon value. How can I add a geohash of this field to the result?

Comment: You want it by API or webserver?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `fielddata_fields` in your query, like this:

```
POST /index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "fielddata_fields": [
    "location.geohash"
  ]
}
```

And you'll get something like this, with the `_source` and the geohashes in the `fielddata_fields`

```
{
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "location": "13.0009316,77.5947316"
        },
        "fields": {
          "location.geohash": [
            "t",
            "td",
            "tdr",
            "tdr1",
            "tdr1v",
            "tdr1vw",
            "tdr1vww",
            "tdr1vwwz",
            "tdr1vwwzb",
            "tdr1vwwzbm"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```